# Grey Render? Noobie question

Tags: rendering

As the title suggest I can't seem to render my project. I'm really new to this and I already tried the answers already posted. I'm guessing it's probably a very basic answer, but can't seem to figure it out.

[image]

[image] Here is the file

Comment: Can I ask what version of blender you are using? I just downloaded your blender file and rendered it, and the render worked fine.

Comment: @person132 it's 2.79b, the issue was the one explained below anyway. Thanks for stopping tho!

Answer (score 1):

### Render layers

All your object are in the first and second render layer (you can see that by giving a look at the orange dots in the quick layer bar), while the only layer that will be rendered is the third (see the cursor location in the image below).

Is not immediately understandable, but the boxes under the **Layer** section in the Render Layer panel control the layers that should be rendered.

[image]

You just have to enable the layers with your objects. Shift+click the first and the second box.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no idea how to handle the layers, I tried to use them but I seem unable to place solids in them so I kinda gave up. Thanks again!

Comment: @PernyH If this answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left of the post.

Comment: @PernyH you can move object into a layer by hitting the **M** key.   This moves the active object in to any and all layers you select in the layer popup.